# Combine the contents of two columns into one column using R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I got some data like this

```r
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1), time1 = c(10, 20, 30), time2 = c(15, 25, 35)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I want to create a single column from the two columns in the above data

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), time = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I dont think its the same as converting into long format because I dont want two columns as a result of gather(), with one the names of the columns used and one the values.

Comment: We could use add_row from tibble package. This answer is not in the duplicate question. So where should I post my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` and this should be more general as it can also do reshaping based on other patterns and multiple columns as well.  Note that `pivot_longer` succeeds the `reshape2` function `melt` with more enhanced capabilities and bug fixes

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df1, cols = time1:time2, values_to = 'time') %>%
      select(-name)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#     id  time
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    10
#2     1    15
#3     1    20
#4     1    25
#5     1    30
#6     1    35
```

---

Or using `base R` with `stack`

```
transform(stack(df1[-1])[1], id = rep(df1$id, 2))[2:1]
```

---

Or can use `data.frame` with `unlist`

```
data.frame(id = df1$id, value = unlist(df1[-1], use.names = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to `tidyr`, though that's a good way to do it:

```r
reshape2::melt(dat, "id")[,-2]
#   id value
# 1  1    10
# 2  1    20
# 3  1    30
# 4  1    15
# 5  1    25
# 6  1    35
```

(Normally it includes the pivoted column names as a column itself, so the `[,-2]` removes that since your expected output didn't have it. You can do just `melt(.)` if you want/need to keep it.)